# Flink - Does keyBy() functon partition the flink operator internally?

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In the below code, taken from [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/try-flink/datastream_api.html#frauddetectionjobjava):

```
package spendreport;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.sink.AlertSink;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.entity.Alert;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.entity.Transaction;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.source.TransactionSource;

public class FraudDetectionJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<Transaction> transactions = env
            .addSource(new TransactionSource())
            .name("transactions");
        
        DataStream<Alert> alerts = transactions
            .keyBy(Transaction::getAccountId)
            .process(new FraudDetector())
            .name("fraud-detector");

        alerts
            .addSink(new AlertSink())
            .name("send-alerts");

        env.execute("Fraud Detection");
    }
}
```

---

1. 

Does `.keyBy(Transaction::getAccountId)` function applied on data stream `transactions` perform  partitioning(based on account ID) on incoming data  and perform `process(new FraudDetector())` on each partition, as shown in below diagram?

2)
If yes, How to write a mapper to process data streamed from each partition? Using `.keyBy(Transaction::getAccountId)`?

[image]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyBy` is applied to datastream `transactions`.

After applying `keyBy`, records from `transactions` with same `account ID` will be in the same partition, and you can apply functions from `KeyedStream`, like `process`(not recommend as it is marked as deprecated), `window`, `reduce`, `min/max/sum`, etc.

There are lots of example of using keyBy, e.g. [this link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#keyby)

Comment: Does `alerts.addSink(new AlertSink()).name("send-alerts");` create sink operator per partition?

Comment: @overexchange if you set parallelism of sink operator equals to count of partitions, then yes. If less parallelism than partitions, then some operator will handle multiple partitions.

Comment: Ah... I wouldn't know the number of partitions in hand. Can I `addSink()` with `keyBy(accountID)`?

Comment: @overexchange That's fine to add `addSink` for keyed stream, and you do not have to worries about partitions. You can configure parallelism of data stream to achieve higher parallel processing as long there are enough slots to run tasks.